# Как представить URL в виде структуры сайта

Tags: .htaccess, url

Сайт состоит из только одной страницы index.php. Структура сайта содержится в базе данных и должна пользователю представляться в иерархическом виде:

```
имя_сайта\каталог1\каталог2\....\каталогN
```

Количество каталогов и количество уровней вложения неограничено. Пользователь может в строке браузера удалить часть адреса до i-того каталога и получить информацию по этому каталогу.

Я реализовал эту постановку задачи с использование `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?catalog_name=$2 [L]
```

Т. е. я передаю методом GET в качестве параметра `catalog_name` имя последнего каталога, ищу его в БД и ввожу из БД по нему информацию.

Проблема заключается в том, что при вводе пользователем в адресной строке браузера адреса

```
имя_сайта\каталог1\каталог2\....\каталогN
```

После выполнения сервером команды `RewriteRule`

адресная строка в браузере для пользователя меняется на `index.php?catalog_name=каталогN` (хотя в некоторых серверах остается прежней), что является неудобным для пользователя.

Я бы хотел, чтобы адрес

```
имя_сайта\каталог1\каталог2\....\каталогN
```

В строке браузера для пользователя после выполнения `RewriteRule` не менялся и пользователь не знал что существует

```
index.php?catalog_name=каталогN
```

Comment: Если предложенный ответ решил вашу проблему, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка справа от текста) — так принято на этом сайте. Если нет — задавайте уточняющие вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую ответить:  файл .htaccess переписываем:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?route=$1
```

Это нам даст переменную `$_GET['route']` которая будет содержать всё после `/`. Дальше работаем в `index.php` - парсим эту переменную на составляющие, и выдаём пользователю что ему надо. Адресная строка при этом меняться не должна.

Comment: На мете речь об этом вопросе?

Answer (score 1):

@Shilgen, Вы правы. Все получилось. Только я сделал немного по-другому

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1
```

Спасибо.